# Editable TableOfContents boxes in each Powerpoint slide header

Tags: powerpoint

I would like each slide in my Powerpoint 2013 presentation to have at the top an outline showing the location within the current chapter, something like:
[image]

I would like Powerpoint to create new slides based on this slide template, so I edited the Title+Content slide-type as above, in the Slides Master; I used the slide's default Title box for the title of my first section (Intro), then copied/pasted that box to obtain the boxes for the other presentation sections (Methods, Results).

I expected that, in the newly created slides, I'd be able to edit each of these boxes (highlight current section & current slide position), so as to suit the slide where I am at the moment, in terms of title and current slide.

However, I can only click inside the first box (the default one that Slide Master gave me) whereas the others are just "drawn" in the background. Also, even after clicking in that first box, the existing text disappears rather than being editable.

Also, is there a way to automate this slide layout somewhat? I used white/black dot circle symbols to indicate within-section current-slide number, but is there a smarter way to make this in Powerpoint based on slide count within the current section?

At the very least, I'd like to have editable text boxes at the top of each new slide, with pre-determined names that can nonetheless be edited, and (imporantly) that can be updated all at once from the Slide Master, in case I decide to change my chapter/section names.

Not a trivial task for Powerpoint, I know, but I'm hoping that the knowledgeable good people on here might give some good suggestions/workaround, for which I am grateful in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trick PowerPoint into adding editable shapes to the slide master by inserting a text placeholder and changing to shape to your desired shape. A little clunky but it works.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657160/powerpoint-add-editable-callouts-in-slide-master).

Alternatively, you could write some PowerPoint VBA to create the slides with the desired objects.

### Update

I use PowerPoint 2013. I downloaded your PPT. I wasn't sure whether you were referring to the textbox with the text "replace text ... " or the main text box for the slide. I'll assume you're referring to the textbox with the text "replace text ... " (mind you ... the answer is still the same).

It looks like you're adding a **text box** to the slide master (which is not what I think you want). Add a **text placeholder** like the screen shot below which you add from the Slide Master ribbon. Once added you can change the default text formatting (which is a set of bullet points), and you can change the shape (in this example to a rounded rectangle). I don't believe (?) that its possible to create default text for the text placeholder in Slide Master that appears as default text when the default slide is created using the master.

[image: screen 1]

Then when you leave master mode, you have an editable text box. If you reset the slide, this shape reverts to its default formatting and position, but any text you've added is retained.

You can also change the default text box on the slide master in the same way (shape, shape formatting and text formatting).

[image: screen2]

Comment: seems that any shape of a text box, when inserted from the Slide Master, is not editable in a newly-created slide. I think the easiest workaround (although one that requires some work) is to simply paste this template into every slide, and edit the contents on each slide.

Comment: Unfortunately, with this workaround, if a tiny change is made in the titles heading, this requires manual editing of each slide in the presentation!

Comment: I rechecked ... a text placeholder added to a slide master ... and changed to a shape on the slide master ... then appears on the slide after exiting slide master mode (though you may have to Reset Slide). The "shaped" text placeholder can be moved, have text added and be recolored. If the slide is reset, then the shape reverts back to the characteristics and location as per its definition on the slide master. So I'm not sure why you can't edit on a newly created slide(?)

Comment: That's now how my Powerpoint (2013) does it.. I've uploaded my ppt file here: https://files.fm/u/wnn4p63a , in case you can have a look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry, that should read That's not* how my Powerpoint does it :)

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer! I was indeed not following your suggestion correctly earlier - once I inserted a text placeholder (not a text box) in the slide master, I could indeed edit these in newly-created slides. This is already one step ahead, but it would be really really helpful if there was a way to make each text placeholder contain some default text that can be edited in newly created slides, rather than having to type text anew (from scratch) in each box/placeholder.

Comment: I tried inserting a Context placeholder instead of a Text one, but any text written in the SlideMaster disappears once the box is clicked into in the normal slide, just as with the Text placeholders. Can you think of another workaround?

Comment: @z8080 I can't think of any other workaround ... without resorting to VBA. But you would need to be comfortable with VBA scripting to go down that route.

Comment: In this case I'll just accept your current answer - thanks again.